# Help with Calculated Field Formula

Tags: calculated-column-formula

I need a calculated field formula to compare two dates from two fields - and display the one that is the latest date.

Answer (score 1):

Try some of the following equations in the Calculated Column.

## First option:

```
=TEXT(MAX(INT( FirstColumnName ),INT( SecondColumnName )), "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss")
```

The `TEXT` command allows you to format what is returned. In this case we're setting the integer value returned from `MAX` into a date/time format of `[Day Number]-[Month number]-[Full year] [Hours]:[Minutes]:[Seconds]`. Like noon today being `20-09-2018 12:00:00`

Here's an example comparing the **Created** and **Modified** of a signup sheet:

### Setup:

[image: Setup]

### Result:

[image: Result]

## Second Option:

If you're fine with the default formatting that SharePoint does you can also just check max and return a date/time value.

`=MAX(INT( FirstColumnName ),INT( SecondColumnName ))`

Here we got rid of the `TEXT` and just use the systems default formatting. Days are marked off as an integer and the hours/minutes are a fraction of some sort. So we let SharePoint decide how to display it by telling it the number returned from `MAX` is a date value.

### Setup:

[image: Setup 2]

### Result:

[image: Result 2]